# Spark Groupby: allow one record in more than two groups

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have an RDD whose keys are like `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5...]`, now I want to group the records into several intervals to process them parallelly, but the groups I want to divide them intersect with each other.

For example, I want to group them into the following groups: [1~10], [5~15], [10~20]..., in this way both [1~10] and [5~15] will need the record `7` for processing.

How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PySpark Numeric Window Group By](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48467215/pyspark-numeric-window-group-by)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe recalculate the keys?

```
class Bucket:
    def __init__(self, min_, max_):
        self._min = min_
        self._max = max_

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0}~{1}".format(self._min, self._max)
    def get_bucket_or_none(self, key):
        if self._min <= key <= self._max:
            return str(self)
        else:
            return None


def make_new_key_using_bucket_list(buckets_list, x):
    return_list = []
    for bucket in buckets_list:
        new_key = bucket.get_bucket_or_none(x[0])
        if new_key is not None:
            return_list.append( (new_key, x[1]))

    return return_list


rdd = sc.parallelize([(1, "A"), (5, "B"), (10, "C"), (10, "D"), (5, "E"),
                      (10, "F"), (7, "G"), (14, "H"), (18, "I"), (23, "J")])

buckets_list = [Bucket(1, 10), Bucket(5, 15), Bucket(10, 20)]

rdd_new_keys = rdd.flatMap(lambda x: make_new_key_using_bucket_list(buckets_list, x))

print rdd_new_keys.groupByKey().map(lambda x: (x[0], list(x[1]))).collect()
```

[('10~20', ['C', 'D', 'F', 'H', 'I']), ('5~15', ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']), ('1~10', ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'])]

Comment: Thank you! I think this works. `flatmapping` a single record into multiple ones with corresponding keys is a good idea.